# Let a user copy the source code... of an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can understand basic javascript and jquery but I'm having a hard time understanding how to allow a user to see the source code of an element for example.

If I have an element on a webpage like this

```
`<p>Hi I'm an element</p>`
```

every body knows it will be displayed as this

```
Hi I'm an element
```

but I want a user to see this in its source code form

```
`<p>Hi I'm an element</p>`
```

How on earth is this done??

Comment: Your title seems to be the opposite of what the picture does.  What the picture appears to do is allow someone to write source code, then preview what that source code looks like.

Comment: are you trying to generate the form from html when button cliked

Comment: do u need to have that source in clipboard? Smth like "click this button and source code is in your clipboard". If yes, then i have to tell you that some browsers don't allow using clipboard directly from JS (like Firefox). You will need to use some small flash app for this if you need it to be cross-browser script.

Comment: Note that using innerHTML (which is what jQuery's *html* method uses) will not necessarily return exactly the same markup that the user entered, nor be consistent across browsers. Neither is really a technical issue, but it may confuse users who get back something different to what they entered.

Comment: thank you all. You guys and gals are great.  @ coldtold and devrtix.net that is exactly what i want to do. thank you for the tip. i think i found a plugin that might do the trick. called Zero Clipboard. @ Erik sorry for not being clear. @ robg ill use the innerhtml and see what i can come up with. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to get the HTML of an element, then show it somewhere as plain-text. We can use `.html()` to get the HTML and then `.text()` to output the same HTML as plain-text:

```
//on the click of a link
​$('a')​.on('click', function () {

    //append a container with the plain-text HTML of an element
    $('body').append($('<div />').text($('form').html()));
});​​
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YbJfs/

Note that this does not get the actual `<form>` tag, but you could place the form in a container, select the container, and then use the `.html()` if that container and you'll have the `<form>` tag as well.

Also, if you want to add the HTML to a form input or text-area, you can use `.val()` rather than `.text()`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YbJfs/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use...

```
element.outerHTML;
```

...though it isn't technically the "source code". It's the HTML rendered by the browser, which may have some differences.

Also, you need a shim for Firefox 10 and lower.

```
function outerHTML(el) {
    return el.outerHMTL || document.createElement('div')
                                   .appendChild(el.cloneNode(true))
                                   .parentNode
                                   .innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: @user1119742: The top line works in IE8 and below. If you need Firefox support, you'll want to use the second code block instead. It first tries the `.outerHTML` property, and if that doesn't work, it runs the fix.

Comment: if you dont mind how would you apply this to a simple <p>this a message</p> element.

Comment: @user1119742: If you've already selected the `p` element, and have it stored in a variable called `my_para`, you'd do `var markup = outerHTML(my_para)`. If you haven't selected the `p` from the DOM, you'll need to do that first.

Answer (score 1):

to grab the html of an element either use native javascripts innerHTML, or if you want to use jQuery use html() method. Examples ...

javascript:

```
var html = document.getElementById('myOb').innerHTML;
```

jQuery:

```
var html = $('#myOb').html();
```